# slow list view scrolling on iPad when scrolling in an overflow:auto div

Tags: ipad, ios5, jquery-mobile, cordova, webkit

I am developing a Phonegap app for the major os platforms and am currently testing it on an iPad with iOS 5. Im using jquery mobile. So for large screens i've used the splitview jquery mobile plugin. http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/  
I've put a

```
$scrollArea.css('overflow-y','auto');        
$scrollArea.css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling','touch');
```

to make the page scroll instead  of using iscroll like the plugin was using. Now whats happening, is that the page isn't loading/repainting as the user scrolls. I have a list of 100 items and i scroll through them.
  The scrolling itself isn't slow, but it takes almost a full second for the new list view rows to pop into view after it has been scrolled. Before that it's a blank area.

On observing, i can see that the the list items don't pop into view until the scrolling has come to a halt. (momentum scroll)

A similar issue is here http://forum.jquery.com/topic/help-with-slow-list-view-scrolling-on-ipad-when-scrolling-in-an-overflow-auto-div

What can i do to make this work normally?? The same thing works fine on android tabs. pls help.

**EDIT:** If i use only

```
 $scrollArea.css('overflow-y','auto');
```

then i dont face this issue of momentary blank areas after scrolling, but then the scrolling is painfully slow.

Please don't suggest using iScroll. Already tried that. its much much slower that what i get with -webkit-overflow-scrolling, and i cant use it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that iOS 5 still draws `1024x1024px` blocks at a time, so almost anything off-screen will have to be rendered when brought into the view-port. Funnily enough this is more of a problem with iOS than Android (which usually just isn't the case).

Comment: So what do u suggest is the best way to give users a common scroll experience on both??  or atleast a usable experience on iPad??

Comment: I didn't post my comment as an answer because I have very little experience with iPads, but here is a promising article I found on Google (the search term was `html ipad pre-draw offscreen content`): http://kaioa.com/node/103.

Comment: I have the same problem that the scrolling is either slow (with just "overflow: scroll" or it takes until the scrolling stops to redraw the screen (with "-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch". It only happens with heavy content (like an iFrame from YouTube, transparent PNGs etc. And also "-webkit-overflow-scrolling" breaks my z-indexes. :-/

Comment: Offtopic: If nobody has a solution, do I get my "money" back? :)

Comment: no u don't get it back :)
i ended up using iscroll only :(

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. :) Hm, the thing with iScroll is: When the scrolling container is across the whole page, you can't zoom anymore (because iScroll prevents all touch gestures from bubbling). Or do you have a solution for this case?

Comment: i havent added the zoom feature yet. but i guess i will have to work on that too soon.

Answer (score 23):

### My Approach

So, I tried a lot and I read even more about this problem. I ended up with a solution which is "OK" to me (because it works), but which is definitely not near to "perfect".

When using this CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow:                   scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

you run into a lot of problems when having a complex design (in my case a fullscreen background image), and it gets even worse, when using absolute positioned elements and `iframes`. (Which is - of course - both the case I needed).

So, what did the trick? Basicly this CSS:

```
.container > * {
    -webkit-transform:          translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

With this rule the content was almost all the time rendered right away without getting those blank areas. Only when scrolling down the first time very fast it's a little flickering.

But be careful with the rule `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`. Using this rule heavily on many child elements forced Safari to: sometimes slow down but almost all the time to crash. The best thing is to wrap all content elements into a single `div`, works fine.

**Done?** Not really. There is still the `iframe`-issue: ("argh")

### iframe

When the `iframe` is not fully in the visible part of the container at the start it gets cropped or is not even displayed at all. This could sometimes also occur when scrolling around. So, I tried to force Safari to re-render this part anytime scrolling is completed and came up with this:

```
//using jQuery
var container   = $('#container');
var iframe  = $('#iframe');
container.scroll( function (event) {
    iframe.css( 'marginLeft', 1 );
    setTimeout( function() {
        iframe.css ( 'marginLeft', 0 );
    }, 1 );
});
```

The thing with the scroll event on a touch device is, that it's only triggered when the scrolling has come to an end, so this function is not fired at anytime but when the momentum has come to an end. The short movement is actually not visible.

So, maybe this is helpful for somebody.

### Further information

Here a few more links on this issue:

- On how the scroll event is fired in iOS:

  [javascript scroll event for iPhone/iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad)
- Bug report of this problem to Apple:

  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7893031/1456376
- `iframe` example with the same problem:

  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8275972/1456376

Comment: +1 just for the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` part alone. I didn't know about this, and for my simple list of items, it made it a  lot easier to scroll through the list. Thanks.

Comment: yet another +1 for the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; this was great!

Comment: yep, next step for everyone has to be some "thanks for the translate3d(0,0,0) on children". that hint helped me a lot lot as I had big crashes; only understanding that it was due to this overflow-scrolling thing but without finding out y

Answer (score 1):

We have used the plugin below in our project, did you try this one out?

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/experiments/scrollview

On iOS it uses hardware acceleration to render the scrolling. It is rather easy to use, all you have to do is to assign an additional class to your div.

We did have some issues on Android 2 with this plugin, to overcome those issues we changed the `scrollMethod` property in `jquery.mobile.scrollview.js`.

I hope it helps you solve your scrolling problem