# “-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch” - scrolled content is hidden?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, webkit

So I found a problem with my website so have added in

> “-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch”

So that the scrolling left-right now works when content overflows (all the content is within an iframe). However I've noticed that when you scroll either vertically or horizontally within this iframe any content that wasn't initially draw on the page is not shown, it's just white.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It would seem with reference to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8275972/1386656 - there is a problem with iFrames when used in combination with -webkit-overflow-scrolling, any work a round for this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cantina.co/2012/03/06/ios-5-native-scrolling-grins-and-gothcas/

This pretty much sums it up, and provides one pretty poor but usable implementation. The fault lies with Apple and this will be a temporary workaround.