# scrolling issue with -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch

Tags: html, iphone, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using Phonegap 2.5 for the iPhone application.I am also using query mobile. Its giving scrolling issue when I use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

and after scrolling content disappears:

[image]

Header and footer are fixed.
this is the code I am using for the div which is scrolling div:

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 75%; margin-top: 10%; overflow-y: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);">
    <!--some content -->
</div>
```

when I remove `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` the content doesn't disappear but it doesn't scroll like native.
I can't figure it out what is the problem?

**UPDATE:** It works fine on ios 6 simulator. screenshots are of iOS 5 device.

Comment: Try out this: -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
Maybe it is somehow related to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8110580/1307609

Comment: I have found overflow touch is buggy on IOS 5.

Comment: @Zsolt Okay I will try it

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't see your html markup though, try to call this script...

Give id to your popup div.

## HTML

```
<div id="yourBox" style="">    
    <!--some content -->    
</div>
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourBox').trigger("create");
});
```