# Custom icon fonts not displaying outside of viewport

Tags: ios5, fonts

I am testing custom icon fonts in a web app using Safari / iOS 5.1. The icons show up in the viewport on page load, but when I scroll down past the viewport they are missing. If I inspect an element and make any minor change, the missing font's will appear, but again, only those fonts in the current viewport.

Here's an example of the CSS:

`.icon-test:before {
    content: "\e025";
}`

Everything works fine in Safari 6.1, the problem is only occurring in iOS 5.1. Has anyone experienced this problem?

EDIT: As I was debugging, I disabled position:relative in the code inspector and the icons started appearing correctly.

Here's the test CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'custom';
src: url('fonts/custom.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/custom.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.icon-test-1, .icon-test-2 {
font-family: 'custom';
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
/*font-size: 28px;*/
color: #666666;
}


.icon-test-1:before {content: "\e000";}

.icon-test-2:before {content: "\e00e";}

.btn    {
position: relative;
top:4px;
float:right;
clear: both;
display: block;
height: 50px;
}
```

Here's the test HTML:

```
<div style="height:200px;width:500px;overflow: auto;">
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-1"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-2"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-1"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-2"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-1"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-2"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-1"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-2"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-1"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-2"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-1"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-2"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-1"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-2"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-1"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-test-2"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide any more details about your css?

Comment: Added CSS and HTML. I can solve this issue by removing position:relative and top:4px, and replacing with padding. But I may need to use relative positioning, so any clarification on this matter is appreciated.

Comment: Found solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808110/css3-property-webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch-error/7893031#7893031) and [also here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110580/ios5-images-disappear-when-scrolling-with-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch/8275972#8275972).

Comment: -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);

...seems to do the trick.

Comment: If you found the solution please write it up as an answer (and then remember to accept it)

Answer (score 0):

Adding...

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

...to parent element(s) fixed the problem with font icons not displaying outside the viewport when scrolling down in iOS 5.

Removing...

```
position:relative;
```

...also eliminated the bad behavior, but I couldn't completely roll with that, since I needed to position some of my font icons.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808110/css3-property-webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch-error/7893031#7893031) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110580/ios5-images-disappear-when-scrolling-with-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch/8275972#8275972).