# Phonegap android page scrolling issues while using google maps

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, handlebars.js

Form elements on page scroll separately on loading map. If there is no map in the page, there is no issue. Same page has no issue in iOS version. Whole contents are wrapped in a div with class 'scroller' and have css,

```
.scroller {
     overflow:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Scroller height is window height.

Phonegap version 2.7 is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!

Got the answer from , https://stackoverflow.com/a/10122689/1855383

Added some css

```
.scroller {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.scroller > * {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```