# iOS Safari css position fixed when textarea is focused

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile-safari

I have a simple html page long enough that the user requires to scroll the page. I want at the bottom of the page to have a div with postion:fixed and inside him a textarea.
When a user clicks on the text area and the virtual keyboard appears I want the div position to stay at bottom , not in the middle of the page like in this pic: [image]

Here is the code I've used: https://jsfiddle.net/capz19yg/

```
    .inputFixed{
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0px;
        right:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
        background-color:lightgrey;
    }

    textarea{
        height:40px;
        width:300px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:5px;
        right:10px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        border:none;
    }


<div class="inputFixed">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Is there a fix to this? maybe some javascript to make the correction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of several SO questions. See https://gist.github.com/avesus/957889b4941239490c6c441adbe32398#gistcomment-2193547 for details.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problems is related to a well known bug in iOS Mobile Safari, that happens with scrolling / focus jumping and fixed positioning. Many people have written about it and many did hacks or changed their design to partially solve the issue.

As I reference, have a look at:

- [Stackoverflow: Safari in ios8 is scrolling screen when fixed elements get focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001977/safari-in-ios8-is-scrolling-screen-when-fixed-elements-get-focus)
- [Issues with position fixed & scrolling on iOS](https://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios)
- [Mobile Safari (Whyyyy?!)](https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/mobile-safari-why/)