# CSS bug -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: ios, css, react-bootstrap-table

I am having an issue with the last three or so entries of my tables being hidden on mobile, most notably iOS.  I have researched this css bug and seen multiple solutions.  The issue is that this scrolling option seems to be set on about every html element in the routes displaying tables, unlike in the posts with solutions.  The solutions I have tried are:

1. -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
2. position: static;

Those were taken from this post:
[CSS3 property webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808110/css3-property-webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch-error)

This is the site with the issue http://ec2-54-175-36-237.compute-1.amazonaws.com/#/Results

That link has a table on it, again, pretty much iOS specific. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which version of iOS are you using? Device simulator running 11.1 renders without any issues.

Comment: The bug is on every version of iOS we have tested.  If you have not seen the footer, you have not seen the bug.  There are definitely hidden entries.